# Create one tasks report for multiple projects in Tuleap

Tags: tuleap

I'd like to create one tasks report for all projects. As the avilable option you can creat trackers report for every project individual.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some hints on writing a good-quality question.

Comment: do you have any idea about Tuleap?